# Increment class instance counter in Python

Tags: python

I'm not well versed in Python as I have a Java background.
I have this simple class:

```
## Class declaration
class SemVersion:
    major: int
    minor: int
    patch: int

    def __init__(self, major, minor, patch):
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
        self.patch = patch

    def incrementMinor(self):
        print(self)
        self.minor = self.minor + 1
        return self

    def toString(self):
        return self.major + "." + self.minor + "." + self.patch

    def toSnapshotString(self):
        return self.toString() + "-SNAPSHOT"
```

The following statement throws an error:

```
newDevelopVersion = releaseSemVersion.incrementMinor()
```

Exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\devenv\java\apps\vsb-letters-transfer-api\release_preprod.py",
> line 41, in 
> newDevelopVersion = releaseSemVersion.incrementMinor()   File "C:\devenv\java\apps\vsb-letters-transfer-api\release_helpers.py",
> line 17, in incrementMinor
> self.minor = self.minor + 1 TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

I'd like to understand how Python can manage not to recognize it as an integer as I declared it as such and just increment the way I asked it.
I'm sure there is a reasonable explanation for it.
I don't see how I asked anywhere to add a string to an int or anything of that nature.

Many thanks.

Comment: How are you creating instances of `SemVersion` (e.g. what arguments?). Type hints are only that, they do not enforce typing.

Comment: if you make the function call with an integer in this case it would treat it as an integer

Comment: Where/how are you instantiating your `releaseSemVersion` instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't enforce types from annotations. The annotations are primarily for documentation purposes.

You are likely passing in an `str` to the constructor when you initialize your object which would have made the interpreter think `releaseSemVersion.minor` is a string instead of an `int`.

---

You can avoid this by adding a check in `__init__()` as follows

```
def __init__(self, major, minor, patch):
    if not isinstance(major, int):
        raise TypeError('major must by of type int')
    
    if not isinstance(minor, int):
        raise TypeError('minor must by of type int')
    
    if not isinstance(patch, int):
        raise TypeError('patch must by of type int')

    self.major = major
    self.minor = minor
    self.patch = patch
```

Comment: Stupid question... but aren't these languages supposed to recognise types? I will accept it if it's like that. Seems  a bit dumb to cast a 1 to a 1. Maybe that's just me.

Comment: Not all programming languages enforce variable types. Python follows the philosophy of duck typing. All objects in python have a type, but the interpreter doesn't check types until prompted. There are both pros and cons to the approach and there's a lot of debate around the topic.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, some considerations when using Python:

- Python do not enforce type, type hints just helps you and others to understand what is expected on some method or function
- Variables and method name must be in `snake_case` format, following the best practices described on [pep8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/)

Now, refactoring your example, you should be able to perform your desired operation with:

```py
class SemVersion:
    major: int
    minor: int
    patch: int

    def __init__(self, major, minor, patch):
        self.major = major
        self.minor = minor
        self.patch = patch

    def increment_minor(self):
        self.minor = self.minor + 1
        return self

    def to_string(self):
        return self.major + "." + self.minor + "." + self.patch

    def to_snapshot_string(self):
        return self.toString() + "-SNAPSHOT"


# Your class instance
develop_vision = SemVersion(
    major=1, 
    minor=2, 
    patch=3
)

print(f"Initial value of minor: {develop_vision.minor}")

develop_vision.increment_minor()
develop_vision.increment_minor()

print(f"New value of minor: {develop_vision.minor}")
```

Now, if you want to check your constructor arguments type, pydantic can help you!

```bash
# Make sure that your virtual environment is active

$ pip3 install pydantic
```

Adapt your class to use pydantic validations

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, StrictInt


class SemVersion(BaseModel):
    major: StrictInt
    minor: StrictInt
    patch: StrictInt

    # You don't need build a constructure anymore, pydantic do it for you

    def increment_minor(self):
        self.minor = self.minor + 1
        return self

    def to_string(self):
        return self.major + "." + self.minor + "." + self.patch

    def to_snapshot_string(self):
        return self.toString() + "-SNAPSHOT"


# Your class instance
develop_vision = SemVersion(
    major=1, 
    minor=2, 
    patch='10'
)

print(develop_vision)
```

If you try to run this code, using a string like '10', you will get an exception from pydantic, like this:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jns/Desktop/stack.py", line 23, in <module>
    develop_vision = SemVersion(
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for SemVersion
patch
  value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
```